# Is $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ a maximal ideal in $Z[x]$? What about $\langle x^2+1,5\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am thinking that $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is not a maximal ideal in $Z[x]$ but am having trouble coming up with a solid argument. Also I am confused about what/how to read the second term  $\langle x^2+1,5\rangle$ and how that is related.
Thanks!

Comment: An ideal $I$ is maximal in $R$, a commutative ring if $R/I$ is a field. Clearly, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle  \cong \mathbb{ Z}[i]$ which is not a field.

Answer (score 3):

The ideal $(x^2+1)$ is not maximal, because $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+1)\simeq \mathbf Z[i]$, which is an integral domain, but not a field.

The ideal $(x^2+1,5)$ is not maximal either, because
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+1,5)&\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+1)=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x-2)(x+2)\\&\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x-2)\times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x+2)\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z,
\end{align}
which is not even an integral domain.